# Manager not accessible in Tomcat 6

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

When I try to access the url for manager as below I am getting 404 error.

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

My "tomcat-users.xml" contain the following.

```
 <role rolename="manager"/>
 <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager"/>
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here.?

Comment: Make sure the server is running.  Hit http://localhost:8080

Comment: Yes.I am able to get the Tomacat Home page

Comment: Yes, it is not commented

Comment: Some changes require a server reboot.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as eclipse?